# Find nth Smallest element from Binary Search Tree

Tags: data-structures

How to find nth Smallest element from Binary Search Tree

Constraints are :

1. time complexity must be `O(1)`
2. No extra space should be used

I have already tried 2 approaches.

1. Doing inorder traversal and finding nth element - Time complexity `O(n)`
2. Maintaining no. of small elements than current node and finding element with m small elements  - Time complexity `O(log n)`

Comment: I am not able to cross the second constraint ---> `No extra space should be used`! Are you sure about this?

Comment: Yes... I was also not able to get answer for this constraint ... hence thought of putting this on stackoverflow to get some hints.. 
Interviewer was specifically looking for this constraint..

Comment: What do you mean by `No extra space`? Also, as far as I know, you will never get `O(1)` out of a binary tree.

Comment: The second constraint, in my opinion, just means that you should do it in an iterative way and not recursively. As for the first constraint, I have no clue how and **if** it can be satisfied.

Comment: The question lacks specificity. Do you want to support a query such as "Give me the 5th smallest element" and then later "Give me the 8th smallest element"? Or do you want to build a tree that will always give you the 4th smallest element, for example? If the latter, you could maintain a reference to the 4th smallest element and update it in O(log n) (perhaps faster) whenever a smaller element is added or removed. However, that would require O(1) space in the tree to maintain the reference. If the tree is static, then there are other possibilities. Need more information.

Comment: Query will be like 'Give 5th smallest' or ' Give 4th smallest' .

Comment: If the tree is static and stored in an array in breadth-first order (like a heap is stored), that meets the "no extra space" constraint. It *might be* possible to compute the index of the nth smallest element in constant time, but the only solution I see immediately would require O(log n) time.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think about is to change the data structure that holds the BST in memory. Should be simple if you actually consider every nodes as structure themselves (value, left_child and right_child) instead of storing them in a unordered array, you can store them in a ordered array. Thus the nth smallest element would be the nth element in your array. The extra computation will be at insertion and deletion. But it still would be more effective if you use for example a C++ set (log(n) for both insertion and deletion).

It mainly depends on your use case.

If you do not use data structure for handling the tree (based on array position) I don't think you cannot do it in something better than log(n).